# Best practices for migrating web application from Netscape to IIS?

Tags: migration, dns

We are in the process of developing a .NET based IIS hosted web application as part of a re-platforming project. The original web app is on a Netscape server, in the process of migration we need to point the dns to the IIS server so that the requests are responded by IIS. at the same time we would still need the Netscape server so as to redirect the users from the IIS web app for the regions of the web site which the new application doesn't process (yet).

The old application is frame based, so we plan on using IFrames in the content area (of a master page in web client software factory) and use a URL rewrite engine to render pages from the old system in the iframe.

We also need to point the DNS entry which currently points to the Netscape server to IIS.

Are there and best practices for the above activities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this link can help: [Migrating a Web Server to IIS: Basic Steps](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742537.aspx)

It discussed the steps you can take to get ready for Internet Information Services (IIS). In this article, the author takes a "nuts and bolts" approach to migrating an individual Web server.

You'll find detailed information about migrating configuration settings and content to a server running IIS 5.0 from another type of Web server, such as Apache HTTP Server or **Netscape Enterprise Server**.